# Unable to select "Use a NAT instance instead" in AWS VPC Wizard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I am trying to use the VPC Wizard to create a VPC with Public and Private subnets.  However, during the set-up, I don't see an option for "Use a NAT instance instead", and only able to see the default option of "Specify the details of your NAT gateway".

Can someone tell me why I am not able to use a NAT instance instead?

Image attached for reference.

[image]

Comment: Yes. It appears this option has been removed from the VPC Wizard. You would need to launch a NAT Instance yourself, and create the VPC yourself rather than using the VPC Wizard. Are you following a tutorial, or is this for an actual deployment?

Comment: I was following a tutorial... Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've run into the same issue. Following the Wiley Certified AWS Developer book. Exercise  2.2. Looks like it's out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because the NAT Instance is based on Amazon Linux (v1) and that OS reached end of standard support on December 31, 2020 per [this announcement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html). Also see the [related blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/update-on-amazon-linux-ami-end-of-life/).

I don't see an Amazon Linux 2 replacement NAT.